# Interactive PDF Creation Alternatives to Acrobat?

Tags: forms, pdf, pdf-generation

Are there any good alternatives to Adobe Acrobat for creating interactive PDFs? The terminology is a little fuzzy here - by interactive, I mean "able to be filled in", and not necessarily "scriptable". So this form would be for data collection, rather than report generation which seems to be the common scenario for pdf-related questions on SO.

The trick is that they need to be fillable using Adobe Reader. For those who have not experienced the many frustrations of Acrobat - by default, Reader cannot fill in a form unless it was created using Acrobat Pro >8.0 and has specifically enabled usage rights. That's fine and it basically works (except then Pro users can't save *their* data - WTF?).

Because I am getting frustrated, I would ideally like to avoid Adobe products altogether (that is on the design side, for the users Reader is still a necessity or I would just do it as a db-backed web form). I'm wondering if anyone has has good experiences with alternatives? Either software libraries or products?

Thanks!

EDIT - Thanks, matt b - I'd seen iText before but didn't know it could create forms. Unfortunately, it looks like Reader cannot *save* filled-in data to the forms generated by iText (or generated by OO Writer). I've got the nasty feeling that what I want is fundamentally impossible except using Adobe's own rights management tools. If there are other ideas. I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 4):

You can create fillable form PDFs using **OpenOffice.org** as well as **LibreOffice**.

To create the initial form elements in the *.odt documents, enable the *View* --> *Toolbars* --> *Form Controls* tools, which allow you to add clickable checkboxes + radiobuttons, fillable text fields, pushbuttons and some more to the page(s).

When you're finished with your document, use *File* --> *Export as PDF* with the checkbox *Create PDF form* enabled.

Now your PDF form will be editable (and saveable!) with any non-Adobe PDF viewer.

**NOTE, however:** Adobe uses an own proprietary way to create and fill PDF forms. Adobe Reader does only support to fill PDF forms which were created by an Adobe product (and which have been assigned 'extended rights' so Reader can indeed save the formdata alongside the document).

Adobe Reader will not work with PDF forms you created with OpenOffice.org or LibreOffice ('work' in the sense of: 'allows you to fill+save the form data'.). The technical mechanism behind this is that Adobe digitally sign their form documents with their own key (which is known to the Adobe Reader, and which you agreed to not reverse engineer when you accepted the Adobe Reader EULA...). --

This means:

- Non-Adobe PDF Readers will not be able to 'fill+save' forms created with Adobe products (they can 'fill+print' them however).
- Adobe PDF readers will refuse to 'fill+save' forms created with non-Adobe products (they will 'fill+print' them however).

The latter two points will be true for *all* the tools and utilities mentioned in the other answers to this question. If I'm mistaken here, please let me know in a comment...

Answer (score 2):

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) is pretty much the standard in the java-world for generating PDF files programmatically. Perhaps it can also be used to create PDFs with forms in them as you would like?

Answer (score 2):

The open source page layout tool [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/) has a bunch of features oriented to creating interactive PDF forms. I haven't personally used them, but they appear reasonably complete and are covered by the tutorial.

Scribus is worth knowing about if you ever need to do serious page layout in any case.

Answer (score 0):

XSL FO is some thing we used to create PDF files out of existing form data. Unless you want the fillable pdf to be sent out the client, this is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

IText lets you create Annotations (there are essentially 3 types of 'interactive' components - forms (old style FDF and new XFA) and Annotations. Acrobat and lots of third party tools should let you modify the Annotations values.

There is also a DotNet version of IText called ISharp - both are freeand extremely powerful.

Answer (score 0):

CutePDF Pro allows you to turn a PDF into an interactive form.

Answer (score 0):

Foxit reader allows you to save *any* pdf with the filled in fields.

Answer (score 0):

I recently dabbled with Scribus. I found it to be an excellent tool if one has enough time to configure and play around with it. I highly recommend it. Wufoo is also very good.

I am not a fan of Acrobat / Adobe. A software should make my life easier not challenge me at every step.

If you search the net with these keywords - FREE FORM CREATOR and you can add the word HTML5. 
You will find an array of sites where you can log online and all your clients can have their separate login, fill in data and the form remains in the Cloud and declutter your hard drive. All stakeholders can access the form and edit at anytime. The account can be used as a folder for your business. These forms can be accessed on any device and any platform.

Many of these forms are HTML5 driven, they are so beautiful and fluid. Keep away from macros, they carry viruses.

www.homebasedofficeservices.com