# Are there any credible alternatives to iText for programmatic PDF generation within Java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Anyone come across anything else that is similar or close in quality/features?

Cheers.

Comment: Why not iText? Please care to share.

Comment: The license has recently changed from LGPL -> AGPL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is for example [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org).

Comment: Yes, this is good, <strong>but<strong> it my experience can sometimes be buggy and it's not yet at V 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to take a look, but the impression I'm getting is that iText is the best right now.

Answer (score 3):

There's a pretty thorough conversation about that already:
[Are there any Java PDF creation alternatives to iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377135/are-there-any-java-pdf-creation-alternatives-to-itext)

For what it is worth, I find that PDFBox does most of what is typically required.

Answer (score 0):

Does "programmatic" eliminate XSL-FO?  If not, I've generated them using Xalan and XSL-T.  I prefer iText, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Apache FOP is useful for small data and requires a lot for XSL-FO & needs to have all xml at once.
Pdf box can be 1 promising solution.
i-text was good until its license changed for commercial use.