# How to print PDF files using Java

Tags: java, jsp

In my project I have JSP pages that should print PDF documents

Comment: You can try Jasper, dynamic reporting libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iText, fop or other.

Take a look at:

[Compare these products for PDF generation with Java given requirements inside: iText, Apache PDFBox or FOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625849/pdf-generation-with-java-what-to-use-itext-apache-pdfbox-or-fop)

[Are there any Java PDF creation alternatives to iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377135/are-there-any-java-pdf-creation-alternatives-to-itext)

Answer (score 0):

See the following which will convert HTML to PDF.

https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Easier than working with iText directly.